# Extract content from <div> tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm wondering how I could 'extract' the content from a set of div tags, for further use (like emailing or displaying elsewhere). The tricky part is that the content in the div's is only made after the page has loaded.

This is the div:

`<div class='simpleCart_items'></div>`

I have an understanding of javascript and php,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, very simply:

```
var content = $('.simpleCart_items').html();
```

This, assuming you have only 1 element with that classname. Otherwise, you could get other content

Wrap this with the `ready()` function in jQuery. Please refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thanks! How can I delay the script from grabbing that var until the page has loaded?

Comment: @OwenParsons I added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the content once it's there, as you can't get something that doesn't exists. With that in mind, you'd get it the same way you would any other content.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.simpleCart_items'); // nodelist

for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
    console.log( els[i].innerHTML )
}
```